# delphi : Assign an image by its own name from the database

Tags: delphi, vcl

I want to select the image that will be displayed by its name in the database table. Note that the images are in `PngImageList1` and have the same name. Can I replace the index and put the name instead? Please help.

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   var
cartRow: TFrm;
posX,posY : SmallInt;
P : TPanel ;
IMG : TImage;
larn : TLabel;
larc : TLabel;
lari : TLabel;
larfd : TLabel;
imgname,path:string;
begin
ScrollBox1.DestroyComponents;
posX := 0;
posY := 0;
imgname := FDQuery1.FieldByName('ImagePath').AsString;
FDQuery1.First;
while not FDQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    cartRow := TFrm.Create(ScrollBox1);
    cartRow.Parent := ScrollBox1;
    cartRow.Name := '';
    cartRow.Left := posX - 1;
    cartRow.Top := posY - 1;
    cartRow.Label1.Caption := FDQuery1.FieldByName('CountryAr').AsString;
    cartRow.Label2.Caption := FDQuery1.FieldByName('CountryID').AsString;
    PngImageList1.GetBitmap(imgname, cartRow.CIMG.Picture.Bitmap);
    cartRow.Width := ScrollBox1.Width;
    posY := posY + cartRow.Height + 1;
    FDQuery1.Next;
  end;
```

Database table:

[image: Database table]

PngImageList1:

[image: PngImageList1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of `TPngImageList` introduces a function `IndexByName`:
[PngComponents](https://bitbucket.org/uweraabe/pngcomponents)

In case you cannot or don't want to update, you can implement a similar function in your code based on the original sources:

```
function TPngImageList.FindIndexByName(const AName: string): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for I := 0 to PngImages.Count - 1 do begin
    if SameText(PngImages[I].Name, AName) then begin
      Result := I;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Uwe_Raabe
Yes I have the latest version Can you show me how this is done Can you edit my code because I did not understand how to use it?

Comment: Just change the GetBitmap call like this:
`PngImageList1.GetBitmap(PngImageList1.FindIndexByName(imgname), cartRow.CIMG.Picture.Bitmap);`